# Verbed color names and "-en"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, morphology

"whitened", "blackened", and "reddened"; but "yellowed", "grayed", and "blued".

Is there some rule or is it just one of those things?

"Greened" makes sense; no one is going to say "greenened".

"Pinked" or "pinkened"?

"Purpled" or "empurpled"?

First person to *not* make an *Arrested Development* joke gets a +1 from me.

Comment: You do see "blacked" sometimes. You do it to shoes and you do it when you drink too much.

Comment: Come to think of it, you get both "blacked out" and "whited out" but with very different connotations.

Comment: Yeah, someone said "whiting" to me too -- that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Then again, "whiting" is a sort of fish and "pinked" is something you did with a pair of special shears.

Comment: @MetaEd "Blacking" and "whiting", I think, are extra forms that refer to making something *entirely* black/white. (Also the former refers to application of blacking).

Comment: My back yard greenens every spring, and brownens every autummn.

Comment: You can brown some meat in a frying pan without inflection.

Comment: ...and you used to [pink](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20pinked%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1847&lr=lang_en) someone when you stabbed them. It would seem more logical to **red** them, but I think "pink" there implies it wasn't a serious wound with a full amount of red blood spilled.

Comment: I am surprised that no one has yet mentioned "mauven", "fuschian", and "burn sienna".

Answer (score 5):

It looks like words that end with a hard consonant get the "-en".

Comment: What about 'pink'?

Comment: @Mitch I would use "[pinken](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pinken)", if for no other reason, at least to avoid confusion with something done with a rapier or pinking shears.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer concerns only the colours pink and purple**

**Pink**
Pink ends on a hard consonant thus "[to pinken](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pinken)" would seem logical and the Merriam-Webster indeed lists this as a legitimate form but ONLY as an intransitive verb. According to the Merriam-Webster, the form "[to pink](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pink)" means many things but NOT "to make something pink" . Oxford Dictionaries, however, does list "[to pink](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pink?rskey=urvf1M&result=1)" as relating to colour but ONLY as an intransitive verb.

Strangely enough, none of the dictionaries seem to list a transitive form, which suggests that we should use "to make pink" for this purpose. However, personally (and I think many others with me) would be perfectly comfortable to use "to pinken" as a transitive verb - even though the dictionaries don't agree with me.

**Purple**
Both "[to purple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purple)" and "[to empurple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empurple)" are valid forms.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is more likely to be semantic and morphological than phonetic.  The OED records as both transitive and intransitive verbs *black* (and *blacken*), *white* (and *whiten*), *purple* (and *empurple*) *green, pink, yellow, pink, grey*,  and *blue*, although not all are in current use. The forms *white, black* and *purple* first occur either at roughly the same time as the longer forms, or predate them. *The –en* suffix is found in verbs other than those which indicate a change of colour. The OED begins it etymological note on the suffix with:

> Most of the words of this type seem to have been formed in late Middle
>   English or early modern English, on the analogy of a few verbs which
>   came down from Old English or were adopted from Old Norse . . .’

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fair amount of literature agreeing with JeffSahol's statement that the use of *-en* is related to the sound of the word. According to "Argument Structure and Morphology: The Case of *en-* Prefixation Revisited", by Susanna Padrosa Trias (ASJU, XLI-2, 2007, 225-266):

> a number of authors (e.g. Halle 1973, Aronoff 1976, Siegel 1979, Scalise 1984, Fabb 1988) have noted [the existence of verbs like *redden*] and have claimed that *-en* is the element triggering the conversion of As to Vs. [...] I suggest that there is a single suffix which sometimes has phonological content (the *-en* morpheme) and sometimes does not (the zero-suffix), thus avoiding the unwanted double forms for a unique function. The aforementioned authors agree that there are some constraints on the suffix’s attachment. The suffix *-en* only attaches to monosyllabic As that on the surface end in a single obstruent, preceded by a vowel, which optionally may, in turn, be preceded by a sonorant. If an A violates the condition just stated and there is a related nominal form that satisfies it, then *-en* attaches to the N: e.g. *frighten<sub>V</sub>* (*afraid<sub>A</sub>* has two syllables), and *strengthen<sub>V</sub>/lengthen<sub>V</sub>* (*strong<sub>A</sub>* and *long<sub>A</sub>* end in a nasal).

(p 244)