# Verb form of "to blacken" versus "to brown"

Tags: verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verbed color names and “-en”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49102/verbed-color-names-and-en)

It just *sounds right*, but why is *brown* its own verb when "to make Black" turns into *blacken*?

I assume it's something to do with the -n ending of *brown*. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, and you can whiten, but you can't bluen, yellowen, etc.

Comment: Not forgetting that 'black' itself can also be a verb.

Comment: related: [Verbed color names and “-en”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49102/verbed-color-names-and-en)

Answer (score 11):

The old ***-en*** [Causative/Inchoative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf) suffix is no longer productive in Modern English, but it's still part of quite a few verbs, including *redden, blacken, whiten, darken, lighten, weaken, broaden, gladden, madden*, and *sadden,* among others.

But it doesn't attach to other colors or adjectives, as you note for *brown*; consider also the awesomely wrong verbs **purplen,* **orangen,* **greenen,* and **bluen*.

Interestingly, there is also an ***en-*** prefix with the same meaning -- *cause to be* or *come to be* -- as in *encourage, enlarge, enable, ennoble, embody, emblazon,* etc. These can occasionally be found together, as in *enlighten, embolden, enliven,* and *enhearten.*

Comment: +1: But you didn't account for *embiggen*.

Comment: I also didn't give every example of every usage. _Embiggen_ falls into the last category, and that's why we understand it. And the fact that it's not a productive affix is what makes it a joke on the statue quotation, which is an ultra-formal register.

Comment: Nice observations. It's kind of like "got / gotten". Where AE still uses the older form of the verb, i.e. "gotten", while BE has dropped the "-en" suffix. Further, beget, begot, begotten. Or, "prove, proved, proved/proven", bespoke/bespoken. Sweet, sweeten, nice, nicen. Seems the "-en" suffix fell into disuse in the course of the modernization / simplification of English grammar over the past 100 years or so.

Comment: Wide/widen, deep/deepen. Wise/wisen, (as in "Let me wisen you up.")

Comment: There was an increase in usage of causative/inchoative _-ize_ over the same period, I think. English is full of former causative suffixes, like the old Indo-European Yodated Causative suffix -j- like OE _drinkan_ 'drink' ~ _drinkjan_ 'cause to drink', later palatalized down to _drench._

Comment: BTW, the -en suffix in _proven_ is a different -en suffix that marks past participles in Germanic languages. In German, where the morphology hasn't been lost like it was in English, just about every verb has a unique and mostly regular past participle form beginning with the prefix _ge-,_ and most of the verbs with irregular forms (the sogenannte _"Strong"_ verbs) end in _-en._ The regular, law-abiding verbs (_"Weak"_ verbs, natch) have past participles that end in _-t._ _Singen, Sang, Gesungen_ - Strong; _Lieben, Liebte, Geliebt_ - Weak. It's a handy marking device.