# Difference between "queue" and "enqueue"

Tags: verbs, differences

What is the difference between *queue* and *enqueue* given that both are verbs?

Comment: *Enqueue* (Chiefly AmE) is mostly used in the domain of computing, in contrast with *dequeue.*

Comment: Wow, thanks for the downvotes -.- Why?

Comment: @Kris Yes, I had checked a dictionary and still had doubts. That's why I've asked you, guys, about it.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queue) Merriam-Webster link, definition of 'Queue' as a verb is-

> **queue** verb \ˈkyü\ : to form or wait in a line
>
> transitive verb :  to arrange or form in a queue

and

> intransitive verb :  to line up or wait in a queue —often used with up.

See below two examples of both forms of this usage of queue as a verb -

> The World's Food Fair, Boston. October 1896. Admission: 25 cents. Huge
>   crowds throng the Mechanics Hall convention center. Women queue up for
>   free samples from 200 different vendors: cereals, gelatins, extracts,
>   candy, and custards. —Christopher Kimball, Cook's Illustrated, January
>   & February 2008

and

> The crowd was queuing at the snack bar.

And now look at [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enqueue) definition of 'Enqueue' as a verb from the Oxford Dictionaries-

> enqueue:
>
> VERB (enqueues, enqueuing or enqueueing, enqueued)
>
> [WITH OBJECT] Computing Add (an item of data awaiting processing) to a
>   queue of such items.

While "queue" has a relatively broad usage as a verb(with reference to line up/create a line), "enqueue" is mostly used in computing(specifically- data structures).

Comment: So basically *queue* is normally intransitive, and *enqueue* is transitive. The only real context these days for putting something in a queue (transitive) is in computing. Your two examples before *enqueue* are both intransitive.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Most usage of "queue" as a transitive verb is in computing, ex- he _queued_ his queries in the relevant order.

Comment: The ole [-_en_ and _en_- causative/inchoative affixes](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57678/15299) are not really productive in English any more, and it's common for words with them to either take a different meaning or fall out of use against a zero-derived form. They're a pretty irregular bunch of verbs by now.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does that mean that if I say "queue this item" meaning "put it into the queue to do later" I am formally ok? Or "enqueue" is required in such context because of verb transitivity?

Comment: The environments in which _enqueue_ might be required would be so rare and unusual that they can be ignored. If you're discussing a particular academic field, enquire about usage from its native writers.

Comment: Many computing scenarios, often message queueing applications, specifically use enqueue, rather than queue (eg step 1 open connection, step 2 enqueue message etc). This may be in order to make it obviously distinct from the noun (a queue object) - ambiguity is bad in coding. (Example uses Twilio.com, Hangfire.io etc).

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180428-What-s-the-difference-between-Queue-and-Enqueue-