# Pattern to Old English verbs-of-making-adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, vocabulary, historical-change, old-english

The other night (after hearing someone on TV say "smoothen"), I noticed that a fair number of Anglo-Saxon-derived adjectives tend to come in pairs where the more "distinguished" or "active" adjective becomes a verb by adding *-en* while its opposite adjective is the same as the verb form.

| Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- |
| roughen | smooth (*smoothen) |
| sharpen | dull (*dullen) |
| widen, broaden | narrow |
| brighten | dim (*dimmen) |
| thicken | thin |
| fasten, tighten | loose (but also "loosen") |
| sweeten | sour |

My question is: **Is there a known or theorized linguistic reason for this pattern?** I have at least three hypotheses: (1) The *-en* marker connotes human activity: one must act positively to *brighten* and *sharpen* things, but they will *dim* and *dull* on their own. (2) The marked words are more frequent and/or more important; it's useful to distinguish *[please] brighten* from *[it is] bright*, but the distinction between *[please] dull* and *[it is] dull* is less practically relevant and therefore verbally unmarked. (3) This is entirely a case of confirmation bias.

---

Of course the pattern isn't universal; I can think of more exceptions to the rule than I can followers. I'll list them here, just in case it's useful to someone and/or someone thinks of a reason to move one up into the table above.

| Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- |
| heat (*hotten) | warm, cool |
| speed (but cf. modern "quicken") | slow |
| blacken, redden | whiten |
| darken | lighten |
| gladden | sadden |
| quicken, liven | deaden |
| stiffen | — |
| sicken | — |
| straighten | crook, bend, curve, curl |
| moisten, dampen | wet (*wetten), dry (*dryen) |
| heighten (*tallen), lengthen (*longen) | shorten |
| strengthen (*strongen) | weaken |
| — (*heavyen, *weighten) | lighten |
| — | deafen |
| — (louden?) | soften |
| flatten | — |
| ripen | — |
| fatten | — (*lean) |

Comment: High points for owning confirmation bias, even if not the main player here.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en#Suffix_3  From Middle English -en, from Old English -en, from Proto-Germanic *-īnaz; suffix meaning "made of, consisting of, having the qualities of" applied to nouns to form adjectives. Akin to Dutch -en, German -en, Icelandic -inn, Latin -īnus. See -ine.

Comment: _-en_ is an [old causative/inchoative suffix](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/343828/15299). It's not productive any more. Applied mostly to statives and referred to their changes.

Comment: @JohnLawler: But why to one of a pair and not the other? I guess _now_ I'm also seeing a pattern to the final consonants: -k, -d, -t, -p, -f (-gh) can take -en, but -m -n -w can't. The pairs fitting the pattern are "just" the ones where one antonym ends with -k, -d, -t, -p, -f, and the other antonym ends with -m -n -w? And that pattern is just confirmation bias, or is there a reason for antonyms to differ in their final sounds?

Comment: @Lambie: FWIW, I'm pretty sure your adjective-from-noun _-en_ (wooden, silken) is different from this question's verb-from-adjective _-en_ (blacken, sharpen). John's "inchoative suffix" sounds right to me. Also different: pluralizing _-en_ (oxen, brethren). There are only so many sounds to go around, so we shouldn't be surprised that some common affixes have multiple unrelated purposes. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Yeah, I copied the wrong one from Wikipedia, for sure.

Comment: The causative/inchoative _-en_ is not productive any more, which means that it's degraded to a derivational suffix, not [an inflectional one](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf). Derivations like _-dom_ or _-hood_ only attach to certain words (*_brotherdom_, *_candlehood_)  because those words have been common.

Comment: Hi, do the answers to the previous question [Verbed color names and "-en"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49102) help? Is there anything more that you'd like to see covered?

Comment: @herisson: [Verbed color names and "-en"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49102/verbed-color-names-and-en) does indeed seem to confirm my new-in-the-comments theory that the _-en_ attaches to words ending in "hard consonants." The only anything-more in this question is "is there a reason for antonyms to differ in their final sounds?", which is _probably_ unanswerable, but one never knows...

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer due to the wide-ranging examples in your question. Based on the evidence I've seen, this is an *accident* that depends on two things: (a) when the verb in question was formed and (b) whether an *-en* form emerged from the time when that suffix was most generative in English. Beyond that, when both forms exist, it's a matter of luck or guessing whether the *-en* form is more successful.

### The *-en* suffix is primarily generative in Early Modern English (EME)

Something you'll notice if you look up words like *widen* and *sweeten* is that they are relatively recent formations from the 16th century, and not themselves Old English formations. The Oxford English Dictionary elaborates in its definition of the suffix [*-en* (5)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61505):

> Etymology: Most of the words in sense 1 [darken, deepen, harden, madden, moisten, widen] seem to have been formed in late Middle English or early modern English, on the analogy of a few verbs which came down from Old English or were adopted from Old Norse; e.g. fasten v. < Old English fæstnian ; brighten v. < Old Northumbrian berhtnia ; harden v. < Old Norse harðna.

There are other ways these verbs are formed too, such as from nouns or directly from Germanic strong verbs, but for the adjective-verb pathway, most of your examples are early modern. I'll put the first use of each verb in brackets to illustrate a pattern:

| Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- |
| roughen [1582] | smooth [1340] (*smoothen) |
| sharpen [1530] | dull [c1374] (*dullen) |
| widen [1566], broaden [1727] | narrow [eOE] |
| brighten [intrans. OE, trans. 1567] | dim [a1300] (*dimmen) |
| thicken [1425] | thin [c900] |
| fasten [OE], tighten [1727] | loose [a1225] (but also "loosen") |
| sweeten [1552] | sour [1340] |

I see a pattern. The left column almost always comes from late Middle English or Early Modern English, with two from Old English; the right column comes largely from Middle English with two from Old English. The *-en* suffix we are looking at wasn't generative in the period of Middle English the verbs from the right column come from, but it was generative in the period after. If a word like *sour* had formed as a verb in the 1500s, we may have indeed seen *souren*.

Actually, that's not a bad idea. Sometimes those verbs *also* formed.

### A few of the verbs in the right hand column *did* develop *-en* forms, even if they didn't persist

If you go looking, you can actually find some *-en* forms of those latter verbs in the Early Modern period:

- [smoothen, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182764), from 1655. Several subdefinitions.
- [dullen, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/58349), from 1832. Marked as *rare*.
- [dimmen, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52933), undated. Marked as *rare*.
- [loosen, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/110198), in first definition rare/obsolete and from 1382 (Wycliffe Bible), in subsequent definition from 17th century from 1645 (Milton)
- [souren, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/185198), marked as *northern dialect*: "intransitive. To become sour." First use in 1570.

In most cases these remained rare or dialectical. *Smoothen* and *loosen* are somewhat common, and they seem to really catch on in the Early Modern period. Aside from some possible phonological reasoning or the fact the *-en* forms had prior competition from simpler forms without *-en*, it's an accident or guessing game to explain why *souren* isn't at least like *loosen*. Similarly, it's a matter of guessing why some words in the left hand column do have common verbs without *-en* (*[rough, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167846)*, e.g., "rough the passer") but others don't (*[sharp, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177572)*, whose uses are almost all obsolete).

Comment: Nice answer! You brought up "madden," which I just now thought I _could_ add to the table as "madden | calm, tame," but I've decided that's a bit of a stretch, since the most typical verb antonym of "calm" would probably be "anger", not "madden".